# cross-compiling with non-gcc-like compiler

Tags: bazel

(From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/LQfL6c-6Wqg/uinZMCTYCgAJ)

Hi--

Is it possible to use bazel to cross-compile using a toolchain where the compiler flags are not remotely gcc-like?

For example, bazel seems to want/need to use -MD -MF foo.d, but the toolchain I have doesn't support these flags, and I do not know of a way to filter these flags from the compile invocation.

The only thing I can think of is to point the CROSSTOOL at some wrapper scripts to muck with all the arguments.

--Rob

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, CROSSTOOL would encapsulate all the toolchain/platform specific flags and Bazel won't hardcode any flags specific to gcc/linux. We're getting there, although at much slower pace than expected (it's quite painful process).

So you should be able to write your own crosstool (or generate one similarly to how [bazel does it](https://www.bazel.build/blog/2016/03/31/autoconfiguration.html)) that would not emit -MD -MF foo.d. Since we're in the process of migrating many internal crosstools, Bazel is trying to be smart and will add features that your crosstool is missing. Check [CppConfiguration.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/76555482873ffcf1d32fb40106f89231b37f850a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppConfiguration.java) and [CppLinkActionConfigs.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/76555482873ffcf1d32fb40106f89231b37f850a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppLinkActionConfigs.java) for these "patches".

And regarding wrapper scripts, that's what bazel has been doing for MSVC builds, translating gcc-like command lines into cl.exe style. We are slowly removing logic from these scripts as crosstool is more powerful (e.g. Bazel@head now doesn't use wrapper scripts for linking at all).